# In-class member initializer of unique_ptr to nullptr error with explicitly defined default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, explicit-constructor, in-class-initialization

I have a class template that assigns a unique_ptr to nullptr using an in-class member initializer. If I use `MyClass(){}`, all is well. If I use `MyClass() = default`, I get:

```
conversion from 'std::nullptr_t' to non-scalar type 'std::unique_ptr<A>' requested
```

Here is a minimal example which fails to compile with g++ 4.8.4:

```
#include <memory>

class A{};

template <typename T>
class Test
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> data = nullptr;
public:

    //Test() {} // works fine
    Test() = default; // compiler error

};

int main()
{
    Test<float> test;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, we will not be minimizing your unknown (to us) code for you.

Comment: @SergeyA that was a very helpful comment. Well done.

Comment: Your code is compiling fine on gcc: [Try it online](http://ideone.com/fD6Hyr)

Comment: One of the purposes of creating an SSCCE is that now you have a baseline between what works and what you have done. Gradually introduce more of your actual code until you are able to repro.

Comment: @Anedar Sorry if I wasn't clear - the example I posted there IS compiling for me. My real code is not, but best I can tell that is the same pattern that I have. I was looking for answer like "if OtherClass doesn't have XYZ defined, then this will happen."

Comment: How can we tell you why it is not working if we do not have code that is not working?

Comment: I have changed the online-example to a forward declaration. So at the point the unique_ptr is defined the compiler doesn't know anything about `OtherClass` other than that is indeed a class - and it still compiles. So sorry, but with that few information i could not even guess what it might be...

Comment: Ok sorry all, I got a SSCCE working and it is posted.

Comment: @Anedar See updated question.

Comment: see updated online example: still compiling

Comment: @DavidDoria It still compiles for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b68a4c68c6665e2

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @NathanOliver g++ 4.8.4

Comment: @DavidDoria It looks like you hit a compiler bug/standard feature not added yet.  [it compiles](http://goo.gl/ZfnMPe) with 4.9.2 and above.

Comment: Is there any way to clean up the mess of comments that I caused by posting a bad first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments already, this is a compiler bug. It's not a problem in the library implementation of `unique_ptr`, but a language issue that is fully reproducable without any standard library headers, seemingly only in class templates:

```
struct A { A(int); };
struct B { A a = 1; };
B b; // ok
template <typename T> struct C { A a = 1; };
C<void> c; // error
```

Luckily, it's a compiler bug that you can work around. The implicit conversion is mishandled. Force an explicit conversion and even GCC 4.8 accepts it. In your case, that means:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> data = std::unique_ptr<A>(nullptr);
```

Comment: unique_ptr is nullptr by default, too, right? Is it good or bad practice to either explicitly set it to nullptr or not?

Comment: @DavidDoria Yes, that is the default. I can think of valid arguments for and against explicitly providing an initialiser and don't recall seeing consensus on a best practice.

Comment: Care to ouline them in 600 characters or less :) ?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<A> data;` would be a simpler workaround, surely

Comment: @DavidDoria For: some types are left uninitialised by default. As it's not always obvious whether a type would be left uninitialised, all class members should be initialised explicitly. Against: the unnecessary initialisers may cause clutter and detract from the logic that's more worthy of reading.